# the total no. of true rows after refreshing by year

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

i am working on a c# project in that i have made this query which is

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_column) 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  Datepart(mm, record_column) = @myMonthSelected 
AND    Datepart(yy, record_column) = @myYearSelected
```

it counts the total number of rows after sorting and now i want it to modify that a column which is having a "Bit" data type, i want to count the total number of true rows by sorting month and year same as the above query. can it be possible to narrow my search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_column) 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  Datepart(mm, record_column) = @myMonthSelected 
AND    Datepart(yy, record_column) = @myYearSelected
AND BitColumn = 1
```

Comment: thank you sir, i am a student so i am little bit confused in such queries, thank you once again for helping

Answer (score 0):

I use the old "sum of bits" trick.  Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(someBitColumn) AS TotalCount
FROM someTable
```

Since I'm at it, here's a variation for counting types of things:

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN animalKind = 'Dog' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END CASE
  ) AS DogCount,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN animalKind = 'Cat' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END CASE
  ) AS CatCount,
  ...
 FROM animals
```

Comment: I think I might have misread your question, though... @nakchak looks to have  better answer.

Comment: oh i have first timer heard such thing. i am a student thanks because of you i explore such thing
:)